# New Edit: Continue to receive msg "Segmentation Fault: 11" when I try to run the program, any ideas?

Tags: c++

Really unsure what to do, all it is is checking if a word matches in the matrix only from left to right. You out the word and the starting position in the command line. So the command "./a.out tcnj 1 1 < 0505matrix" will return true because the letters tcnj start at position 1 1 in the matrix Thanks so much, all help is appreciated!
So this is the matrix only the letters are in 5 rows of 5 (thats what the 5s are) similar to a word search

5 5
u r a q o 
f t c n j 
k r h p r 
e a v o t 
z h g a h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    cout << argv[i] << " ";
  }
  std::string sWord = argv[1];
  int wordLength = sWord.length();
  int startRow = atoi(argv[2]);
  int startCol = atoi(argv[3]);

  int x, y;
  cin >> x >> y;
  cout << x << y << endl;
  vector < vector < char > > matrix;
  matrix.resize(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
    matrix.resize(y);
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
      cin >> matrix[i][k];
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
    if(matrix[startRow][startCol + i] != sWord[i]){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the arguments passed to the program? Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: so the command "./a.out tcnj 1 1 < 0505matrix" will return true because the letters tcnj start at position 1 1 in the matrix

Comment: What is 0505matrix? You need to include information like this in your question otherwise we can't help you. And edit your question instead of putting this information in the comments.

Comment: I tried to add the matrix but im unsure how to add a file but the above letters/numbers are all thats in the file

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is, in the below line,

```
matrix.resize(y);
```

Since it is a two dimensional vector You should do like this.

```
  matrix.resize(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
    matrix[i].resize(y);
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
      cin >> matrix[i][k];
    }
  }
```

Comment: The condition for the 2nd loop should be `k < matrix[i].size()` or `k < y`. Also instead of using `resize` you can use a different constructor: `std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(x, std::vector<char>(y));`

Comment: wow man i didnt get a sgmentation fault msg omggggggg this might be big news, have been stuck on this for soooo long

Comment: unfortunately, the last for loop isnt working cause i added a cout true/false statement respectively and its printing nothing when i run the program

Comment: @Thomas Molloy, I am not getting what you are trying to say. Do you want to display the user inputs.

Comment: figured it out, thanks so much for getting rid of the segmentation fault, took me forever to deal with that