# Keep getting Segmentation fault: 11 and Im unsure why?

Tags: c++

I need to create a program thats finds words from the command line in a matrix and then colors them red. This is the first part that reads for words from left to right. I keep receiving a segmentation fault: 11 from the second nested for loop in int main. I know i dont call the function "right" but that shouldnt effect the segmentation fault should it? Any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

```
#include "colormod.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  Color::Setting red(Color::FG_RED);
  Color::Setting def(Color::FG_DEFAULT);

  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    argv[i];
  }

  int x, y;
  cin >> x >> y;
  vector < vector < char > > matrix;
  matrix.resize(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
    matrix[i].resize(y);
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
      cin >> matrix[i][k];
    }
  }

//THIS IS WHERE THE SEGMENTATION FAULT IS
vector < vector < bool > > empty;
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
  for(int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++){
    if(empty[i][k] == true){
      cout << red << matrix[i][k] << def << " ";
    }
    else{
      cout << matrix[i][k] << " ";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
 }
}
//THIS IS WHERE THE SEGMENTATION FAULT ENDS

void right(vector < vector < char > > &matrix, vector < vector < bool > > &empty, char *word, int x, int y){
  bool check = false;
  int count = 0;
  int wordLength = strlen(word);
  for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
    if(y < matrix.size()){
      if(word[i] == matrix[x][y]){
        count++;
      }
    }
    y++;
  }

  if(count == wordLength) check = true;
  if(check){
    y = y - wordLength;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
      if(y < matrix.size()){
        if(word[i] == matrix[x][y]){
          empty[x][y] = true;
        }
      }
      y++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your matrix is not necessarily square, since `x` and `y` can be different, yet you loop through both row and column using only `x` (`matrix.size()`), so you're going to attempt to access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I've seen pretty much the same code from another user, and pretty sure they had the same problem.

Comment: @crashmstr, someone shared the assignment code with the whole class  )))

Comment: Related: [New Edit: Continue to receive msg “Segmentation Fault: 11” when I try to run the program, any ideas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463626/new-edit-continue-to-receive-msg-segmentation-fault-11-when-i-try-to-run-the)

Answer (score 1):

```
vector < vector < bool > > empty;
```

Creates an empty vector.  Then you try to access elements in it with

```
if(empty[i][k] == true)
```

Since there is nothing in the vector this will be undefined behavior and the cause of the segmentation fault.

You are also using the wrong size for the nested loop in your for loops.  You are using the outer vector size for the size of the inner vector which may or may not be correct.  Your for loops should look like

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix[i].size(); k++)
```

Or you can use ranged based for loops like

```
for (auto& row : matrix)
{
    //now row is one row of the outer vector 
    for (auto& col : row)
    {
        // now col is one element in the row
    }
}
```